# Is it possible to create a desktop gadget in .net for windows XP?

Tags: .net, windows-xp, windows-desktop-gadgets

Can someone throw some lights if it is possible to create a desktop gadget in .net for windows XP?

Thanks,
JP

Comment: Windows XP does not have gadgets. But you can create some customized forms with WPF that looks like a gadget.

Comment: Setve, Can you please suggest any reference material that will help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, windows gadgets were html/javascript based, so unless you're talking about a server side component that a gadget communicates with, I'm afraid not.

Also, as commenteer points out, to have them on XP at all requires a workaround:

http://www.guidingtech.com/4550/install-desktop-gadgets-windows-xp/

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for sharing the information. The applicaiton that I am trying to build will pull information through webservices and I want to display the details in a chart.

Comment: Well .NET will be fine for your web service, but as for creating a gadget for XP, first check for which third-party software you'd need to use to display it before going any further, there is more than one option

Comment: I want to display the information from salesforce.com as a chart in a gadget. I will be connecting to salesforce through webservices.